# How tall is this building?

Tags: geometry

So I would like to figure out how tall a building is and here's what I know.  I am standing 200 ft away from the base of the building and from that point I used a range finder and pointed it to the top of the building and got 700 ft.  So at 200 ft away, at a angle, the top is 700 ft from me.  How could I figure out how tall the building is?

Comment: Simple application of Pythagora's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)?  You have two sides of a right triangle.  $a^2+b^2=c^2$

Comment: Yeah I looked that up but I'm doing it wrong.  I'm not very good at math.  I would like to be able to figure it out but I'm getting some crazy high numbers

Comment: @Matt:  without seeing your calculation we can't say what is wrong.  You have $a=200, c=700$

Comment: @Matt You can use the "edit" button to add information to your question. To make the formula $a^2+b^2=c^2$ as in this answer, type `$a^2+b^2=c^2$`. To make $\sqrt{x}$ type `$\sqrt{x}$`. With a little trial and error, watching the preview pane below the edit pane, you should be able to show the formulas and equations you used.

Comment: Is 670 the answer? If not I'll put down what I'm doing, just tight on time at the moment

Comment: I get closer to $671$

Comment: Yeah you're right.  Thanks.

Comment: It is a general point that if the legs of a right triangle are different, the long one is rather close to the hypotenuse.  If $b \gt a$ you can write $b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}=c\sqrt{1-\frac {a^2}{c^2}}\approx c(1-\frac{a^2}{2c^2})$ and the last term is rather small.

Answer (score 0):

$670.82ft$ or $\sqrt(700^2 - 200^2)$
As the comments above tell you, $a^2+b^2=c^2$.

This can easily be rearranged to $\sqrt(c^2-b^2)=a^2$. Here, $a=x$ ,$b=200$ and $c = 700$.